# /etc/fstab mount fails when mounted by UUID

Tags: systemd, fstab, btrfs

I have a raid10 btrfs volume. When I mount it by UUID, the mount fails and I am booted into emergency mode. When I mount it by drive letter (/dev/sdb/) the server boots fine. Why does this happen?

```
fstab:
/dev/sda2               /boot       vfat    defaults,noatime            0 2
/dev/sda3               /       btrfs   discard,ssd,compress=lzo,noatime    0 0
#e1ee5980-c54b-4b6e-82e2-3dbdcee1dd24   /mnt/store  btrfs   noatime                 0 0
/dev/sdb                /mnt/store  btrfs   noatime                 0 0

gentooserver ~ # btrfs fi show
Label: none  uuid: a782a62a-ffde-49b1-a680-0afeb9cdab0b
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 6.64GiB
    devid    1 size 55.77GiB used 13.01GiB path /dev/sda3

Label: none  uuid: e1ee5980-c54b-4b6e-82e2-3dbdcee1dd24
    Total devices 10 FS bytes used 868.45GiB
    devid    1 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    3 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    4 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sde
    devid    5 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdf
    devid    6 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdg
    devid    7 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdh
    devid    8 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdi
    devid    9 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdj
    devid   10 size 931.51GiB used 174.40GiB path /dev/sdk
```

The actual data on the volume seems to be fine and undamaged. btrfs check returned no errors. systemctl status returned no info on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong.

It should be :

```
UUID=e1ee5980-c54b-4b6e-82e2-3dbdcee1dd24   /mnt/store  btrfs   noatime 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error in below mentioned

```
#e1ee5980-c54b-4b6e-82e2-3dbdcee1dd24   /mnt/store  btrfs   noatime                 0 0
```

1. You add a comment in front of the line, it want to remove.( # --> want to remove)

2.You need to add "UUID =" when the command start.